# Change image of built-in control in ribbon xml

Tags: outlook-addin, ribbon-control, ribbonx

I use Ribbon XML to create a custom Ribbon in Outlook 2010.  In this ribbon I also created a button using Ribbon XML.  This button uses built-in button control(idMso="NavBack").

My question:
Is there a way to overwrite the image when using built-in button control in my case here?

Thanks.

This is my code:

```
<button idMso="NavBack" size="large" />
```

Comment: If this is not possible, how do I call the built-in command in a custom button via the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing image for built-in control is not possible.
And for executing the built-in command of the "NavBack" built-in control I use

```
Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.ExecuteMso("NavBack")
```